# Writing Query in laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Hello i'm new to laravel framework
 i have a MySQL query .This work perfectly fine.

```
select sample.name, ABS((COALESCE(sample.openingbalance, 0)) + COALESCE(trs.TotalAmount, 0)) from sample left join (select ledger,sum(amount) AS TotalAmount from transaction group by transaction.ledger) AS trs on sample.name = trs.ledger
```

I want to write this query so that it is executed in laravel framework
i tried the following query but its not working

```
 DB::table('sample')->select('sample.name',abs((COALESCE('sample.openingbalance',0))+COALESCE('trs.totalamount',0)))->leftjoin('transaction','sample.name','=','transaction.ledger')->select('ledger','sum(amount) as totalamount')->groupBy('transaction.ledger as trs') ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is this.

### Raw Expressions

Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query. These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points! To create a raw expression, you may use the DB::raw method:
sample code

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                     ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();
```

for more info please refer http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects

Comment: maybe you could add an example with the join